# Where is the bytecode of smart contract stored ? And how to get it executed?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development

Well, my question is terse but to the point: Where's the bytecode of smart contract stored?  And how to get it executed ?
From the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afWDt.jpg) and [Ethereum Yellow Paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf) we can see there is codeHash in WorldState ==> Account which is described as:

> The hash of the EVM code of this
> account—this is the code that gets executed should
> this address receive a message call; it is immutable
> and thus, unlike all other fields, cannot be changed
> after construction. All such code fragments are
> contained in the state database under their corresponding
> hashes for later retrieval.

So, it only mentions the **codeHash** but not the code itself. So, it seems I have to read Ethereum's source code to get how it deals with contract bytecode and that's what I'm doing but you know, it's thousands of lines of Golang code. So did anyone have some ideas about that ?

Comment: Same LevelDB as before.

Comment: Yeah, everything is stored in LevelDB but do you know how does it store the bytecode?

Comment: As bytes, I would assume

Comment: I would try to use tools like this https://github.com/hxoht/levelui to explorer the database

Comment: Well, the tool is COOL ! I think it's helpful. Thanks!